# How to set Backpack Crud generator create classes CamelCase

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using backpack and laravel, to create a new crud I use:

> php artisan backpack:crud tag #use singular, not plural

> php artisan backpack:crud product_category #use singular, not plural

When table name is one part it is okay it Create crud like `TagRequest`; however, for the later one it create `Product_categoryRequest` how could I config backpack to create class like `ProductCategoryRequest` like Laravel do.

Comment: Hmm have you tried “ php artisan backpack:crud productCategory”?